# Displaying a pop-up right-click style menu in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, right-click, popupmenu

Strangely, I can't seem to find any details of how this is done in WinRT.  What I want is to display the menu which typically appears when you touch and hold, or right click an icon / image in Windows 8.  I found the event `Holding`, but that doesn't seem to do what I want, in that is doesn't seem to respond to the right mouse click.  Do both of these events need to be handled separately?  Are there any built in events, or does everyone have to roll their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard controls replace your context menu scenario with the use of the AppBar or the Settings charms depending on what you would do (AppBar would be more contextual), so you would select an item on screen - likely by clicking or cross-swiping and you would either automatically display the AppBar or allow users to do the edge gesture to display the AppBar, then the "context menu" options would show up in the AppBar. That said - Tim Heuer's [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto) has a Menu control that I believe might be a context menu implementation you are looking for if you want to do something non-standard. Note though that it might not work as well for users as an AppBar would and it might be less discoverable too.